# autologin ipcamera as part of a slideshow

Tags: image, autologin

Here is a simple script to login automatically to my ipcamera. The view from the ipcamera is integrated as a moving picture in a slideshow [stills] on my webpage, which can be viewed anonymously. [that is why a want to automize the login, i.e. not to bother the viewer with inlogcodes, nor myself].
When I login via the "authentication required" popup from the remote web-adress of the ipcam [which is different from the slideshow's url all is going well and the integration succeeds, so let us skip this part.

This is the login script:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
<!--
function login() {
document.form1.action="http://86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi";
document.form1.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<BODY bgcolor=#000000 onLoad="login()">
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="login" VALUE="video">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="password" VALUE="video">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now the "authentication required" popup still appears with empty fields. I don't see . Hope somebody can explain why this script doesn't work and maybe also has a suggestion for its solution. 
BTW replacing the action property [url] in the script with the empty string [as was the case in the original script] and moving the action=url into the Form tag does not result in a camera view, although the authentication req does not pop up now, which does not mean that the login succeeds.

Appreceate all help,
Wimsch

Answer (score 0):

Put your credentials in camera URL:

`document.form1.action="http://user:pass@86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi";`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, though the result is still confusing me. When I use the local address of the ipcamera [within my home LAN] the authentication req is still popping up on top of the slideshow, which is going on including the camera view shot as intended [so the login is correct] Why then the pop up window does not disappear? Thanks again!

Comment: How am I supposed to answer that without knowing ANYTHING about your camera or network setup? I guess, after you get image from camera, you make another HTTP call and this time it's without username and password. Check your slideshow thoroughly. Or make new one with only one image and see, what happens.

Comment: Hi, There are some complications. Sorry, I have overlooked your answer. 1000 excuses! In this comment format I can only write an paragraph, which is too little for me too explain the problem. Perhaps you can go to the webpage to see the problem: "http://www.atelierfransvandestaak.nl/slideshow.html". Now, your code works fine for accessing the camera [as visitor] inside the local network and outside [remote addr]. But AFTER login on the camera, I want to return to slideshow of which the camera view is a part, just an [moving] image. But this is blocked by the camera's own webpage.

Comment: [belongs to former message] Big surperise: Starting the slideshow again in a new tab, the authent. req. pop up does not appear again, in which the camera view is randomly called, exactly as I wanted. However for the occasional visitor [lik a passerby] I do not want him to look at the cameraview permanently, which is possible in this two steps way of setting up the slideshow. Hope you have a suggestion to do this in a simple manner. Thanks again!

Comment: Try the way I proposed. I tested - it works. You are passing credentials as hidden fields `username` and `password` to `videostream.cgi`, which does not work, as expected. But if you replace both occurences of `http://86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi` (lines 8 and 88) with `http://video:video@86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi` it WILL work.

Comment: Initially it works indeed. But after a couple of runs of the slideshow  the image stays locked in the camera view; also indicated by the url: 86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi in the browser window, instead of the slideshow's url [above]. This goes the same way in several browsers, indicating that prefixing the second occurence of 86.95.237.226:8884/videostream.cgi with "video:video@" means literally login the camera in which your are already logged in, for this is called again on every run. Maybe autologin is a bad idea: browsers behave unpredictable, whereas manual login gives no problem.

Comment: @user2317959 There must be a read-only/guest user in your camera. Remove authentication on it and everything will be OK. Another way - set up proxy, which is authenticated once. What is complete model name of this device?

Comment: Hi David. Model name of this ipcamera: Elro C903, which is identified in the authentification request as "ipcamera_000DC5D7D4A4". When you replace ../videostream.cgi with ../main.htm and sign in on its main address you see also the sourcecode and parameters [in javascript]. Know nothing of proxy [not enabled in my LAN]. Setup of the camera does not allow guest, nor blanks. Sure you can create a user labeled "guest"; this I did with "video" with the leas privilege [visitor]. I figured out that the remote login applet in IExplorer is already filled in, in G's chrome it does not even appear.

Comment: Remote address of the ipcamera "http://86.95.237.226:8884/main.htm" sign in as "admin" [no pw].

Comment: That's some strange camera, I must say - I added user and it rebooted instantly. By the way, live video on this camera will work only in Chrome or Firefox, as it streams MJPEG which makes it incompatible with Opera and Internet Explorer. I wouldn't do this, if I was you. As for still images - there is FTP option in it's menu and you can upload image to your web server periodically, which will eliminate all problems with credentials along with possible load problems with camera, which does not look capable of handling more then 10 connections at a time.

Comment: And I checked - unfortunately there is no "public" mode on it, username at least must be provided. I think, you should really use FTP feature and use uploaded image in your slide show.

Comment: IExplorer puzzles me since it is recommended by the manufacturer of the camera as the browser 'with full functionality'. IE starts spontaneously downloading the videostream, treated as loose images [i think because of the img tag in the script], which IE does by default to 'speed up' the browser, but in fact slowing down. I don't see how to prevent this while the slideshow runs. Following the "Internet Options" you can only empty the temporary internetfolders on quitting the browser. Firefox and Chrome do it well, the camerashot is treated the same as the stills and scaled up in FULL SCREEN.

Comment: BTW I don't see how to run a slideshow within FTP, that is, outside a browser. The full screen view only suggests that the images are not dependent on a browser window, which is for me an essential property of all images, including the camera view. Furthermore, my provider does not support anonymous FTP login, so there is no advantage in skipping http. Thanks!

Comment: No, no and no. You must use FTP to transfer data **to** your web server, not from it. Camera connects to your web server via FTP, puts files there and then you distribute them as other pictures via web server. So, you don't need anonymous FTP account, you provide camera with the one your hosting provider gave you.

Comment: Hi David,
Sorry about this delay. I have contacted my provider about streaming via ftp. He does not recommend this, for this will be seen by a remote client as an attack and thus blocked. He suggests finetuning the script. Your suggestion to upload camera shots works well for stills but this is not wat I want for the slideshow, since inserting a snapshot misses the point. Here I want a moving image in realtime, i.e. the camera's videostream in cgi format, which will be recognized by the browser as an image [mjpeg]. Uploading a recorded videostream [avi] will not work as part of the show.

Comment: @user2317959 Well, then you will have to deal with the fact, that MJPEG is no decoded successfully by all browsers. IE and Opera, for example.

Comment: Found a script which seems to work well with IExplorer; the code refreshes the camera snapshot at a rate of 10 fps. Now motion is ok!       <BODY bgcolor=#000000>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function reload() {setTimeout('reloadImg("refresh")',100)}; 
function reloadImg(id)
{
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
var rand = Math.random();
obj.src ="http://86.95.237.226:8884/snapshot.cgi?user=guest&pwd=&t="+rand;
}
</script>

<img src="http://86.95.237.226:8884/snapshot.cgi?user=guest&pwd=&t=" name="refresh" id="refresh" onload="reload()">

</BODY>
</HTML>